# Chrome extension with xmlhttprequiest to remote server. Always rejected

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest, chrome-web-store

So i have chrome extension.
It's doc to pdf converter . 
To convert doc files in pdf im using remote server . 
Domain where this server located is selected as homepage for extension on web store edit page.
Inside extension my settings in manifest.json is :

```
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://myserverdomain.com/ https://myserverdomain.com:3000/; object-src 'self' https://myserverdomain.com/ https://myserverdomain.com:3000/",

 "permissions": [
            "management",
            "https://myserverdomain.com/",
            "https://myserverdomain.com:3000/"
        ],
```

So when im tring publish extension with docTopdf part it always rejeted.
But when publish without docToPdf part - publish success.
My damain placed on https . On my local machine it works perfect with remote server in developer mode.
Google says that when i added docTopdf part code i didn't comply all they extension rules.

Here is upload code function :

```
uploadFile = function() {
        var data = new FormData(),
            url = "https://example.com:3000",
            xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        data.append('sampleFile', inputFileContainer.files[0]);

        xhr.open("POST", url + "/upload", true);
        xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

        xhr.send(data);

        xhr.onload = function() {
            var blob = new Blob([xhr.response], {
                type: "application/pdf"
            });
            var fileName = "Converted.pdf";
            saveAs(blob, fileName);
            setConvertFormStatus(1);
            resetFileFields();
            if (xhr.status == 200) {
                showAlertForm('success', "File converted!");
            } else {
                //if something goes wrong
                showAlertForm('danger', "Server error!");
            }
        };

    },
```

For blob and saveAs im using

- https://github.com/eligrey/Blob.js/
- https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/